# How would you populate a field based on another field

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

From the admin panel I want to populate a slug field based on a certain text field

eg.

Title: My Awesome Page

would automaticaly populate

Slug: my_awesome_page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There used to be a prepoulate_from option for the SlugField up to 0.96.  It became an admin option after that. [See here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#prepopulated-fields) for reference on that.

Alternatively, you could override the model's save method to calculate the value of the slug field on save().

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170337/django-signals-vs-overriding-save-method) may be helpful, too.

Answer (score 1):

There is also an app called django-autoslug which provides a field type AutoSlugField.  Using that, you could have:

```
class Something(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_lenght=200)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title')
    ...
```

This AutoSlugField has many nice features, such as generating a slug so that it is unique either globally of combined with some other field (maybe a category or the year part of a DateTimeField).

See http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-autoslug for further details.

Comment: Thanks @sfletche for fixing that typo!