# Django model save self.field.rel.to.DoesNotExist

Tags: python, django, django-models

I found several times([one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5452014/1531116), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1641021/1531116)) that people do the same things that I do:

```
class TempUser(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    bank_account = models.ForeignKey(BankAccount)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.bank_account:
            bank_account = BankAccount()
            bank_account.save()
            self.bank_account = bank_account
        super(TempUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But I got next exception:

```
 File "models.py", line 134, in main
    fill_predefined_data()
  File "models.py", line 121, in fill_predefined_data
    user.save()
  File "models.py", line 41, in save
    if not self.bank_account:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 343, in __get__
    raise self.field.rel.to.DoesNotExist
__main__.DoesNotExist
```

Answer (score 3):

You may either change your TempUser model

```
bank_account = models.ForeignKey(BankAccount, null=True)
```

or change your condition to:

```
if not hasattr(self, 'bank_account'):
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but probably the problem is with the fact that the `TempUser` is not created yet.

One thing you can do is to use `pre_save` [(look here)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#pre-save)  or `post_save` and put there the creation of `BankAccount`.

or you can actually save the `TempUser` with `commit=False`, crete the `BankAccount` and then save the `TempUser`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you think either of those links are relevant. Both of them access normal fields on the model - id and char fields. You are accessing a ForeignKey, which of course is a reference to another model instance that may or may not exist. In your case, it clearly doesn't exist.

The easiest thing to do is to check for the FK id rather than the actual object:

```
    if not self.bank_account_id:
        bank_account = BankAccount()
        bank_account.save()
        self.bank_account = bank_account
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `bank_account` is not created. 
Do you have any mandatory fields in `BankAccount`?