# Multiple inheritance in django. Problem with constructors

Tags: python, django, constructor, multiple-inheritance

I have a model like this:

```
class Person(models.Model,Subject):
    name = ..
```

The class Subject is not supposed to be in the Database so, it doesn't extends from models.Model:

```
class Subject:
    def __init__(self,**kargs):
        _observers = []
```

my problem is that the constructor of Subject is **never called**, so i've tried adding this to the class Person:

```
def __init__(self):
    super(Person,self).__init__()
```

but now i have an error saying that **init** takes 1 arguments but 7 are given, and the only thing i'm doing is

```
>>> Person.objects.get(pk=1)
```

now i'm lost =S do you have any idea how the constructor of person should be?

BTW: i'm using django 1.1 and python 2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, use new-style classes (ones that inherit from `object`). Second, read about how python's super behaves in multiple inheritance scenarios: http://fuhm.net/super-harmful/

There is also a nice talk covering it: http://europythonvideos.blip.tv/file/4000758/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django's `post_init` [signal](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/).  It's invoked after the model is instantiated, and is passed the instance that was created.