# post_save signal for multiple related models

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I need to trigger any changes of some models. My models are: Brand, Product, Package. `Package` has `fk` to `Product` and Product has `fk` to `Brand`. So when some instances of these models are changed or created or deleted, I need to send signal. Can I implement it with `post_save` signal? I thought that if I write `post_save` signal for lower model: `Package`, then any changes with `Brand` or `Product` will be triggered. But it's not

Comment: `post_save` is associated to a `save` method of a `Model`. So it will be executed only when that specific `save` method is triggered.

Comment: you have to write post_save signal for each of your model

Answer (score 0):

Why your signals are not triggered? Django's `post_save` is triggered in the end of model's `save()` method ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#module-django.db.models.signals)). When you are updating your `Package`, `Product` still contains only a key to the `Package` model. So `Product` is not calling `save()`.

What you can do:

1. Create several `post_save` signals.
2. Override models' `save()` method.

To bind several `post_save` signals you simply do:

```
post_save.connect(do_package_stuff, Package, weak=False, dispatch_uid='package_post_save')
post_save.connect(do_product_stuff, Product, weak=False, dispatch_uid='product_post_save')
post_save.connect(do_brand_stuff, Brand, weak=False, dispatch_uid='brand_post_save')
```

[Overriding](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) `save()` is easier (and I can say more recommeneded). You can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170337/django-signals-vs-overriding-save-method?rq=1) if you are instrested in what is better.