# Should I prefer one general signal instead of multiple specific ones?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

When the user creates a product, multiple actions have to be done in `save()` method before calling `super(Product,self).save(*args,**kwargs)`.

I'm not sure if I should use just one `pre_save` signal to do all these actions or it is better to create a signal for each of these actions separately.

Simple example (I'm going to replace `save` overrides by signals):

```
class Product(..):
    def save(...):
        if not self.pk:
            if not self.category:
                self.category = Category.get_default()
            if not self.brand:
                self.brand = 'NA'
        super(Product,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
        ...
```

**SO**

```
@receiver(pre_save,sender=Product)
def set_attrs(instance,**kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        instance.category = Category.get_default()
        instance.brand = 'NA'
```

**OR**

```
@receiver(pre_save,sender=Product)
def set_category(instance,**kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        instance.category = Category.get_default()

@receiver(pre_save,sender=Product)
def set_brand(instance,**kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        instance.brand = 'NA'
```

This is just simple example. In this case, the general `set_attrs` should be probably enough but there are more complex situations with different actions like creating `userprofile` for `user` and then `userplan` etc.

Is there some best practice advice for this? Your opinions?

Comment: I would say for maintainability it would be better to split them up. But I generally try to avoid using signals and instead use manager methods etc.

Answer (score 0):

To put the facts out simply, it could be pointed out as a single piece of advice,

If action on one model's instance affects another model, signals are the cleanest way to go about. This is an example where you can go with a signal, because you might want to avoid `some_model.save()` call from within the `save()` method of `another_model`, if you know what I mean.

To elaborate on an example, when overriding `save()` methods, common task is to create slugs from some fields in the model. If you are required to implement this process on multiple models, then using a `pre_save` signal would be a benefit, rather than hard-coding in `save()` method of each models.

Also, on bulk operations, these signals and methods are not necessarily called.

From the docs,

> Overridden model methods are not called on bulk operations
>
> Note that the delete() method for an object is not necessarily called when deleting objects in bulk using a QuerySet or as a result of a cascading delete. To ensure customized delete logic gets executed, you can use pre_delete and/or post_delete signals.
>
> Unfortunately, there isn’t a workaround when creating or updating objects in bulk, since none of save(), pre_save, and post_save are called.

For more reference,

- [Django override save() or signals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170337/django-signals-vs-overriding-save-method/171703)
- [Overriding predefined model methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods)
- [Django: signal or model method?](http://www.lexev.org/en/2016/django-signal-or-model-method/)