# Is there a way to set a Django model IntegerField default to the ID of the newly created record?

Tags: python, django

Lets say we have the following model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    some_int = models.IntegerField()
```

I would like the value of `MyModel.some_int` to default to the value of `MyModel.id`.

For example, immediately after creating a new record in an empty version of MyModel, I could call `MyModel.objects.get(id=1)` and receive an object with id=1 and some_int=1. Is there a way to do this?

Edit: My current workaround is to set the default to 0, then go back and populate the value with the `id` of the created record, but that is messy.

For context: On an existing model similar to `MyModel`, I am being asked to add a new column that will render using the `MyModel` index obsolete as the reference point for the records in that model. Instead, I am adding a new, secondary column, that should store the values of the old IDs for previous records, and new values for future records. To do that though, I need to populate the column first.

Answer (score 0):

In short, check out [post-save signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/signals/#post-save). Also check the generic [guide to signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/signals/) if you haven't used them before. Alternatively, [overload the `save()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170337/django-signals-vs-overriding-save-method).

To elaborate a bit, Django [does allow using a callable as `default` for an IntegerField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#default).
However, because fields are defined as class variables - not instance variables - you can't access `self` and by extension `self.id` directly.

Therefore, you could grab the next `id` within such a callable using any of a number of methods (that would be a different question, one already answered several times on SO), and set your value to that ... **but** in that time, between reading that value and instantiating your `MyModel` at which point it is actually assigned an `id`, another `MyModel` could have been created and "stolen" that `id`, and now you have a row that has the incorrect `some_int` field that doesn't match its `id`.

Depending on your use case, this may not be a concern.

In general for *any* use case I don't believe there could possibly be a one-step solution. Setting the value after creation once it has been assigned an `id` is the only solution, "messy" though it is. The only question would be if Django has anything built in to assign a value after creation more clearly, a role that either overloading `save()` or using signals should fulfil.